# Why is holiday coded as MemorialDay in pandas USFederalHolidayCalendar?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a list of the holiday rules in the provided USFederalHolidayCalendar in pandas:

```
>>> from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
>>> USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules
[Holiday: New Years Day (month=1, day=1, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f735dbb5158>),
 Holiday: Dr. Martin Luther King Jr. (month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+3)}>),
 Holiday: Presidents Day (month=2, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+3)}>),
 Holiday: MemorialDay (month=5, day=31, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(-1)}>),
 Holiday: July 4th (month=7, day=4, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f735dbb5158>),
 Holiday: Labor Day (month=9, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+1)}>),
 Holiday: Columbus Day (month=10, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+2)}>),
 Holiday: Veterans Day (month=11, day=11, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f735dbb5158>),
 Holiday: Thanksgiving (month=11, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': TH(+4)}>),
 Holiday: Christmas (month=12, day=25, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f735dbb5158>)]
```

Is there a reason Memorial Day is `MemorialDay` while all other holidays have spaces in the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported as a bug and resolved.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9760

Comment: It does appear to have been fixed, but from this PR from June 17, 2019 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26912